# What was Kirito's actual family name?

Tags: sword-art-online

Most of you will say Kirigaya, but that is his adopted family name.  Kazuto's mother was Midori's sister and was married to a man from a different family.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [the fan wiki](https://swordartonline.fandom.com/wiki/Kirigaya_Kazuto), his surname was Narusaka (鳴坂) prior to his adoption.

> Born on October 7, 2008, Narusaka Kazuto was adopted by his aunt and uncle a year after his birth, when his biological parents died in an accident.

According to [this news article](https://www.monstersandcritics.com/anime/sword-art-online-season-4-release-date-sao-unital-ring-light-novels-the-sequel-to-the-four-cour-alicization-anime-spoilers/) and some other sources I found, this was revealed at the beginning of *Unital Ring*, originally in [the January 2018 issue](https://twitter.com/sao_wikia/status/939465711772209152) of Dengeki Bunko, which publishes SAO as a serialized story.